# How to simulate a call to HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"] with Rhino Mocks?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, httpcontext, http-caching

**Short version:**

How to get Rhino Mocks to simulate a call to `HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"]` and return expected data?

**Long version:**

I need to simulate a return value from the `HttpContext.Cache` with Rhino Mocks. I'm using the following code in the `TestInitialize` method of my (Visual Studio) unit test

```
// All these are fields on my Unit test class.
foo = new Foo();
mock = new MockRepository();
context = mocks.DynamickMock<HttpContextBase>();
var cache = context.Stub(x => x.Cache).Return(HttpRuntime.Cache);
```

So far so good. Now I tried the two followings:

```
cache.Stub(x => x["MyKey"]).Return(foo);
```

and

```
context.Stub(x => x.Cache["MyKey"]).Return(foo);
```

The first one won't even compile. Visual Studio tells me that I can't "*apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.IMethodOptions'*".

The second one compiles but I get a `NullReferenceException`. I guess this is because I didn't call yet `mock.ReplayAll();`. When I move this line inside my test (before or after `mock.ReplayAll()`) I still get a `NullReferenceException`. The exception does not have any inner exception. However, when I hover on the `Cache` of `x.Cache`, I get the following error message as a value for `x.Cache`: "*'x.Cache' threw an exception of type `System.InvalidOperationException`*" and the message of the said exception is "*Previous method 'HttpContextBase.get_Cache();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.*".

Well, I think I understand why it happens as long as `mock.ReplayAll()` hasn't been called but I don't know why it happens after.

So in a word, how can I get this to work? How to get Rhino Mocks to simulate a call to `HttpContext.Cache["MyKey"]` and return expected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually there is no need to stub it. After calling `mocks.ReplayAll()` I just need to insert whatever I want into cache using

```
_context.Cache.Insert("MyKey", foo);
```

The only drawback is that there seems to be no way to use this in the initialization method of the test.